# Java location of components during drag and drop in GridLayout

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, jlabel

I'm trying to make simple excercise with drag and drop of an icon from one JLabel to another, and completely stuck. I will be glad if someone can help me and explain shortly why I'm wrong.

What I want to do, is to set label icon as null when mouse pressed on label, and set this icon to label on which mouse is released. 
JPanel is on LayeredPane - because next I want to do is to display JLabel with this icon during dragging. But this is for future.

Problem for now:
I cannot correctly set icon to label when mouse released.. 
As commented in code:

- 1st way - cannot set icon to lab4, when set icon on lab2 and want to go back to lab1 - NullPointerException
- 2nd way - mouse presses location is always in the same place. When I click on Lab1 and release mouse on lab3 - icon is set to lab1

Code:

```
public class Main extends JFrame{
private JLayeredPane layeredPane;
private JLabel lab1;
private JLabel lab2;
private JLabel lab3;
private JLabel lab4;
private JPanel mainPanel;
ImageIcon yellowCircleIcon = new ImageIcon("circle_yellow.png");

public Main(){

    Dimension size = new Dimension(400, 400);

    layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
    getContentPane().add(layeredPane);
    layeredPane.setPreferredSize(size);
    layeredPane.addMouseListener(ms);

    mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2));
    layeredPane.add(mainPanel, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
    mainPanel.setPreferredSize(size);
    mainPanel.setBounds(0, 0, size.width, size.height);

    lab1 = new JLabel("111");
    lab1.setBackground(Color.black);
    lab1.setOpaque(true);
    lab1.setIcon(yellowCircleIcon);
    lab1.addMouseListener(ms);

    lab2 = new JLabel("222");
    lab2.addMouseListener(ms);

    lab3 = new JLabel("333");
    lab3.addMouseListener(ms);

    lab4 = new JLabel("444");
    lab4.setBackground(Color.black);
    lab4.setOpaque(true);
    lab4.addMouseListener(ms);

    mainPanel.add(lab1);
    mainPanel.add(lab2);
    mainPanel.add(lab3);
    mainPanel.add(lab4);

    setSize(400, 400);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
}

MouseListener ms = new MouseListener() {

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {

        //1st way - cannot set icon to lab4
        //when set icon on lab2 and want to go back to lab1 - NullPointerEx.
        JLabel tmp = (JLabel)mainPanel.getComponentAt(arg0.getX(), arg0.getY());

        //2nd way - mouse presses location is always in the same place
        //when I click on Lab1 and release mouse on lab3 - icon is set to lab1
        //tmp = (JLabel)arg0.getComponent();
        tmp.setIcon(yellowCircleIcon);
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        JLabel tmp = (JLabel)arg0.getComponent();
        tmp.setIcon(null);
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {}
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {}
};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main();
}
```

}

Comment: Please see the Drag and Drop Swing Tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/intro.html for the correct way to do this

Comment: Actually I have to do this without using TransferHandler.. I know that this is stupid, but excercise is to do this 'manually' :/

Comment: And, I really wondering why MouseReleased location is working not as I expected in this situation, I really want to understand this mechanism

Comment: You are tryng to move JLabels around? There is a working example at http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/